# Change class of li to active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For styling purposes im using a UL and li class to hold some form selection options. Im going to make the radio button hidden and then use the value on form submit. I figured out how to check the radio box when the `<li>` is clicked but for some reason the selected class isnt added to the `<li>` which holds the radio button.

Heres the code:

```
<ul class="options-num">
    <li><input type="radio" name="group1" value="2000"> 2,000</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="group1" value="2000"> 4,000</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="group1" value="2000"> 6,000</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="group1" value="2000"> 8,000</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="group1" value="2000"> 10,000</li>
</ul>
```

Below is my javascript, this works for setting radio as checked when li is clicked but doesnt set selected class:

```
$(".options-num > li").click(function(){
    $(".options-num > li").find('input[type="radio"]').removeAttr('checked');
    if($(this).find('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked','checked')) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
    }
});
```

This is what i tried first but didnt work

```
$('.options-num li').click(function(){
    var radio = $(this).children('input[type=radio]');
    if (radio.is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
        //$("#foo").toggleClass(className, addOrRemove);
        //$(this).('.options-num li').addClass('selected');
    } /*else {
        $(this).parent('li').removeClass('selected');
    }
})
```

Comment: `.find('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked','checked')` doesn't do what you think it does - this code is trying to set the radio button (which you actually would want to use `.prop('checked')` for - http://api.jquery.com/prop/ - ) and you want to just verify boolean truthy and add class on match

Comment: tl;dr - change `.attr('checked','checked')` to `.prop('checked')` and you should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/bb6fp28p/

```
<ul class="options-num">
            <li><input type="radio" name="group1" value="2000"> 2,000</li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="group1" value="2000"> 4,000</li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="group1" value="2000"> 6,000</li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="group1" value="2000"> 8,000</li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="group1" value="2000"> 10,000</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.selected{
    background:green;
}
```

JS

```
$('.options-num li').click(function(){
    $('.options-num li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Learn to use Stack Snippets instead of jsfiddle: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0

Answer (score 0):

The `.attr('checked','checked')` is setting the attribute of the element.

Use `.prop('checked')` and the problem should be fixed!

Comment: can you give me an example im new to jquery, thanks.

Comment: here is a JSFiddle I made for you: https://jsfiddle.net/wmpydy4u/

I used a different method than I previously stated, but this is still valid. Please tell me if this is what you were looking for.